# Odoo - display partner name on stock.move.line

Tags: inheritance, odoo, odoo-14

I'd like to display partner name (partner_id) on stock.move.line

Tried to inherit partner_id like this:

```
class StockMoveLine(models.Model):
    _inherit = 'stock.move.line'
    partner_name = fields.Many2one(related='partner_id')
```

This gives me error "KeyError: 'partner_id'"

I'm new in Odoo and have trouble with understanding inheritance of fields or relating, appreciate any help. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the official documentation:

> [Related fields](https://github.com/odoo/odoo/blob/14.0/addons/stock/models/stock_move_line.py#L23)
>  A special case of computed fields are related (proxy) fields, which provide the value of a sub-field on the current record.
> The value of a related field is given by following a sequence of relational fields and reading a field on the reached model. The complete sequence of fields to traverse is specified by the related attribute.

You can use the [move_id](https://github.com/odoo/odoo/blob/14.0/addons/stock/models/stock_move_line.py#L23) field to access the `partner_id` field on stock move

```
class StockMoveLine(models.Model):
    _inherit = 'stock.move.line'

    partner_name = fields.Many2one(related='move_id.partner_id')
```

Comment: @MatijaAmondi The accepted answer is a copy of my answer

Comment: Sorry, changed accepted answer to yours - it is explained a bit more but I guess your's answer should be accepted since it's first.

Comment: Thanks, I added the official documentation on related fields.

Answer (score 0):

`stock.move.line` object has a *'picking_partner_id'* field which represents the partner information of the picking document.

Field declared with related data type & readonly means it cannot be accessed via query.

Two things:

1. If your purpose is to display value in the form view, then you need to extend the view and add a field at appropriate position.
2. If you want to store value in database & use it in data science, then you need to extend field and add attribute `store=True`

   For example: `picking_partner_id = fields.Many2one(store=True)`

Answer (score 0):

First I will explain this error.

> This gives me error "KeyError: 'partner_id'"

You got this error because the partner_id field is not in the model of 'stock.move.line'.

When you use a related field, the mentioned related field must be in the inherited model then you can access other fields in the related models

Answer

```
class StockMoveLine(models.Model):
_inherit = 'stock.move.line'

partner_name = fields.Many2one(related='move_id.partner_id')
```

You can use the mentioned code instead of your code.

Answer (score 0):

You can use following code

````
_inherit = 'stock.move.line'

partner_name = fields.Many2one(related='move_id.partner_id',store=True)```
````

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

In many2one field you need to add comodel name not related attribute because it's relation between 2 tables ...

```
partner_name = fields.Many2one(comodel_name='res.partner')
```

Comment: I'm not sure how this can be used, using just comodel_name='res.partner' does not give me partner_id as expected